# How to configure automapper to map from two source objects to a destination object?

Tags: collections, automapper, complextype

I am having issues with automapper. I have no clue how to do this and have been searching and trying different solutions. I would appreciate if someone can help me with this.

So here is the issue, I have two source types as shown below:

```
public class User
{
  public string Name {get; set;}
  public int Id {get; set;}
}

public class Product
{
  public int UserId {get; set;}
  public int Id {get; set;}
  public double Price{get; set;}
}
```

I want to map these two to the destination of type UserData:

```
public class UserData
{
  public string UserName{get; set;}
  public int UserId {get;set;}  
  public List<Product> PurchasedProducts {get; set;}
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got this working using a Custom Value Resolver. But I don't think it is the best solution as the resolver is depending on the repository directly. Anyways here is what I did:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<Product, Dtos.Product>();

Mapper.CreateMap<User, UserData>()
     .ForMember(dest => dest.UserName, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Name))
     .ForMember(dest => dest.UserId, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Id))
     .ForMember(dest => dest.PurchasedProducts, opt => 
                  opt.ResolveUsing<User_Products_Resolver>());

Mapper.AssertConfigurationIsValid();
```

And I implemented the custom resolver as follows:

```
public class User_Products_Resolver : ValueResolver<User, List<Product>>
{
    protected override List<Product> ResolveCore(User userObj)
    {                
         var productRepo = new ProductRepository();
         var r = productRepo.Get(p => p.UserId == userObj.Id)
              .ToList<Product>();

         return r;
    }
}
```

Again, I am not sure if this is the correct way to do this. If someone knows a better way, please do let me know.

thanks